# While dreaming, are memories replayed faster or slower?

Tags: sleep, dreams

In Chapter 3 of his book *[Why We Sleep: Unlocking the Power of Sleep and Dreams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1501144316)*, Matthew Walker explains "time dilation in dreams":

> One last temporal distortion deserves mention here—that of time
>   dilation in dreams, beyond sleep itself. Time isn't quite time within
>   dreams. It is most often elongated. Consider the last time you hit the
>   snooze button on your alarm, having been woken from a dream.
>   Mercifully, you are giving yourself another delicious five minutes of
>   sleep. You go right back to dreaming. After the allotted five minutes,
>   your alarm clock faithfully sounds again, yet that's not what it felt
>   like to you. During those five minutes of actual time, you may have
>   felt like you were dreaming for an hour, perhaps more. Unlike the
>   phase of sleep where you are not dreaming, wherein you lose all
>   awareness of time, in dreams, you continue to have a sense of time.
>   It's simply not particularly accurate—more often than not dream time
>   is stretched out and prolonged relative to real time.
>
> Although the reasons for such time dilation are not fully understood,
>   recent experimental recordings of brain cells in rats give tantalizing
>   clues. In the experiment, rats were allowed to run around a maze. As
>   the rats learned the spatial layout, the researchers recorded
>   signature patterns of brain-cell firing. The scientists did not stop
>   recording from these memory-imprinting cells when the rats
>   subsequently fell asleep. They continued to eavesdrop on the brain
>   during the different stages of slumber, including rapid eye movement
>   (REM) sleep, the stage in which humans principally dream.
>
> The first striking result was that the signature pattern of brain-cell
>   firing that occurred as the rats were learning the maze subsequently
>   reappeared during sleep, over and over again. That is, memories were
>   being “replayed” at the level of brain-cell activity as the rats
>   snoozed. The second, more striking finding was the speed of replay.
>   During REM sleep, the memories were being replayed far more slowly: at
>   just half or quarter the speed of that measured when the rats were
>   awake and learning the maze. This slow neural recounting of the day's
>   events is the best evidence we have to date explaining our own
>   protracted experience of time in human REM sleep. This dramatic
>   deceleration of neural time may be the reason we believe our dream
>   life lasts far longer than our alarm clocks otherwise assert.

Source: [Why We Sleep: Unlocking the Power of Sleep and Dreams – B&N Readouts](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/readouts/why-we-sleep-unlocking-the-power-of-sleep-and-dreams/)

If memories replay slower, then wouldn't that make dreams feel shorter (not longer)? [Yohan John writes on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Last-night-I-slept-for-8-5-hours-and-had-a-dream-that-lasted-for-a-month-It-was-full-of-incredible-images-and-interactions-I-woke-to-my-alarm-silenced-it-then-went-back-to-my-dream-for-a-week-before-waking-up-What-was-happening-in-my-brain/answer/Yohan-John) that "replays are typically much faster than actual experience." Now, that would make sense to me.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10521/7001, which itself is a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8386/7001.  My answer actually reviews the very experiment mentioned above!